# Mapa de calor con ggplot

Tags: r, map, ggplot

tengo la siguiente base de datos, de latitud, longitud y ph de agua "tomadas" en fuentes.

```
long <- c(-77.0958901385, -76.7059862868,  -77.0490377322, -77.0082420569, -77.029088411, -76.8875419285)
lat <- c(-11.702568503, -12.2926462918, -12.0510554271, -11.8780894556,  -12.1207933935,  -12.2201247629)
ph <- c(7.64, 7.66, 7.71, 8.10, 8.22, 8.29)
df1<- data.frame(long, lat, ph)
```

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)

df<- df1 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"),crs = 4326)
dflima<-getData("GADM",country="PER", level=3) %>% st_as_sf() %>% filter(NAME_2=="Lima")


df %>% ggplot() +
  stat_density2d(aes(x=df1$long, y=df1$lat, fill =..level..),bins=5 ,geom = "polygon")+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")+
  geom_sf(data=dflima ,col = "#000000",alpha=0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el grafico he intentado hacer uno de densidad, el cual no me grafica la densidad.
**Lo que quiero hacer es un mapa de calor donde el color rojo tome los valores altos de ph y azul los normales y bajos azules por ejemplo, quiero hacer algo parecido al siguiente grafico, el cual es un mapa de calor** el cual esta hecho en otro software.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO POR SU AYUDA**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mediante un gráfico tipo contornos puedes lograr algo parecido al del ejemplo que muestras pero es algo complejo de realizar, básicamente:

1. Podemos usar `geom_density_2d_filled()`
2. Pero el problema es que los contornos se aplican solo al rectángulo formado por lo puntos de tus observaciones, lo que hace es que solo se grafiquen los contornos en una parte pequeña del mapa
3. La alternativa es establecer los limites del gráfico al "bounding box" es decir el rectángulo que contiene todo el mapa
4. Sin embargo, el mapa de contornos se extenderá más allá de Lima, por lo que habría que hacer una máscara para ocultar todos lo que salga del mapa en sí.

---

```
lima_for_mask <- dflima %>%
  st_geometry() %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  st_union()

lima_bbox <- st_bbox(lima_for_mask) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
  st_union()

# Generamos una mascara para mostrar solo lo que ocurre dentro del mapa
lima_mask <- st_difference(lima_bbox, lima_for_mask)

# Obtenemos las coordenadas del rectángulo que contiene el mapa
bbox <- st_bbox(dflima)

df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = ..level..)) +
  xlim(bbox[1], bbox[3]) +
  ylim(bbox[2], bbox[4]) +
  geom_sf(data = dflima, col = "#000000", alpha=0) +
  geom_sf(data = lima_mask, fill = 'white') +
  geom_point(aes(x=long, y=lat), size=2) +
  discrete_scale('fill', 'RB2', palette = \(x) (hcl.colors(x, 'Blue-Red 2'))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

---

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]